# Xlsxwriter merge cells- formatting a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index, xlsxwriter

My program generates a multi index pandas dataframe that I export to excel. After exporting, I used the xlsxwriter functions to set column width, colors etc. So far everything looks good.

I next need to merge few columns but merge function does not retain the text. Have a look at my example sheet.

[image]

I need to merge cells B5:D5, B6:D6, B7:D7. Check the desired format below:

[image]

But xlsxwriter merge command needs the data to be specified in command 
worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4', 'Merged Range', merge_format).

Above excel sheet is just an example. My actual data is very dynamic with greater than 1 experiment. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

> But xlsxwriter merge command needs the data to be specified in command `worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4', 'Merged Range', merge_format)`.

Correct. A workaround would be to read the data the data that you want to merge from the dataframe and use that to write a `merge_range()`.